# How to install and run CPUSim 4.0.11 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, java

I'm going according to the steps mentioned on the cs colby [this site](http://www.cs.colby.edu/djskrien/CPUSim/Version4InstallationInstructions.txt).

First, I installed java on my system by typing the following commands-

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java10-set-default
sudo apt install oracle-java10-set-default
```

[image: Screenshot of java version]

Then, according to the instructions, I downloaded the .zip file, extracted it and then in the terminal typed

```
java -cp .:richtextfx-fat-0.6.10.jar:reactfx-2.0-MR.jar -jar CPUSim-4.0.11.jar
```

But this didn't work. [Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiTp9.png) of command 1 terminal.

Here is a screenshot of all the files that are there in the CPUSim folder,
[CPUSim 4.0.11 contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1AVG.png)

On observing the names of the folders present, I thought that the previous command was wrong. So I tried the following ones,

```
java -cp .:richtextfx-fat-0.6.10.jar:reactfx-2.0-M4.jar -jar CPUSim-4.0.11.jar
java -cp .:richtextfx-0.6.10.jar:reactfx-2.0-M4.jar -jar CPUSim-4.0.11.jar
```

But none of them seems to work. Now when I click on the CPUSim-4.0.11.jar file, nothing happens.
I have just switched to Ubuntu from Windows 10, and have a very little knowledge about how things work here. Please tell me how I could install and run CPUSim 4.0.11 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Can you post the text itself instead of images of program windows with it inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we have downloaded the application:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://www.cs.colby.edu/djskrien/CPUSim/CPUSim4.0.11.zip
unzip CPUSim4.0.11
cd CPUSim4.0.11
```

Then install OpenJDK 8 and OpenJFX

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre openjfx
```

After that you should change command to the following:

```
java -cp .:richtextfx-0.6.10.jar:reactfx-2.0-M4.jar -jar CPUSim-4.0.11.jar \
-m SampleAssignments/Wombat1.cpu -t SampleAssignments/W1-0.a
```

It will launch and you can use it:

[image: CPUSim]

Comment: Thank you very much. Figured out I needed to first remove jdk10 and then type `java -cp .:richtextfx-0.6.10.jar:reactfx-2.0-M4.jar -jar CPUSim-4.0.11.jar`, it's working now. Thank you very much.